# Switch css class angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I know there are some similar questions, but I want to show the css class using "showme" as u can see in the code below:

```
<section>
    <article class="" data-ng-controller="AplicationCtrl" data-ng-init="init();">
        <nav class="navbar menu-nav " role="navigation">
            <a href="" data-ng-click="showme=false;  left=true;">Show</a>
            <button data-ng-click="showme=true;  left=false;" >Hide</button> 
        </nav>
        <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation" data-ng-show="showme">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav customnavhov" id="side-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>          
        <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation" data-ng-hide="showme">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav customnavhov" id="side-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw fa-2x"></i> Random text </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section data-ng-class="{'max-margin': showme,'min-margin':!showme}"> Content </section>
    </article>
</section>
```

The aplication shows depending of the value of showme first or second div, but now I want to make the content on the right has a margin-left depending of wich one is selected.

My controller:

.controller('ApplicationCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

```
    $scope.init = function() {
    };

    $scope.showme = false;
```

} ])

Ok, now this is weird, if i place the buttons inside the section, only works to show/hide the divs, if i place it after the section, only works the margin. Dont know how to fix it.

Comment: add this to section ng-class="{'sect-left': showme }" if you want that class to be added when showme is true

Comment: I just paste the code in a way it partially worked, but before it was like u say and didn't work.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by partially work?

Comment: {'sect-left': true} shows the margin-left i want, but obviusly can't swicth it, what i mean is that i had there {'sect-left': showme } before but didn't work.

Comment: i try it my self and its working fine http://jsfiddle.net/7wvu7f0L/ i noticed you have data-ng-controller="AplicationCtrl" set 3 times, you only need it on article tag all others you can remove.

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation, aniway, seems like it doen't work on my project, I'm looking to dont miss nothing on the example, but it doesnt change the margin on project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-class as suggested by Ismapro. 
Below is an example

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/16283/)**</kbd>

```
data-ng-class="{'one': showme,'two':!showme}"
```

CSS

```
.one{margin-left:25px;}
.two{margin-left:75px;}
```

Comment: Ok, this at least show the margin when showme is false, but doesn't change when its true.

Comment: It does. Please check the fiddle properly. Try clicking on show and hide links which changes margin left of Content.

Comment: It should work as shown in example. You may have some conflicts with scope in your controller or doing something wrong.

Comment: I added a simple version of my controller now.

Comment: Also include the updated html part also as u have in your project

Comment: Looks proper. I think the code you mentioned will not be a complete project code. So some css may be overriding it i guess.

Comment: Ok, i'll try to check all the css code, yes, its part of a bigger project. Aniway, the problem is that it always shows one of the classes.

Comment: @Noble Is there any case sensitive errors in your code? Also check for conflicts in scope variables

Comment: Well, only in the routes now I correct ids, but shows no progress in the margin.

Comment: Since the issue now is other, im going to accept this as answer, but probably tomorrow if i cant make any progress will do a new question with the new issue

Answer (score 0):

you can pearhaps use conditionnal

```
ng-class="{'contentmargin':showme}"
```

with

```
.contentmargin{margin-left:Xpx;}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: but showme variable is accessible from scope.  Is @Navaneeth sample matching the solution you needed ?

Comment: It works in the example, but in my project never switch beetwen them

Comment: what is the content of your sect-left CSS ?

Comment: I change that in html, but its similar to the css from the Navaneeth's example.

Comment: Ok so the problem is not coming from class.